# Response.TransmitFile fails on Safari under SSL

Tags: .net, file, safari

We have a download page where users can download a PDF document.  This page is currently served as HTTPS.  Under Safari **only** (both Windows and Mac) the download will fail 99% of the time after being around 3/4 downloaded (once in a blue moon it will work).  The problem immediately goes away if we replace the "https" part of the URL with "http".

The code is as follows, I believe standard .NET file output:

```
string pdfFile = // generate file here and get the path...
var info = new FileInfo(pdfFile);
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;Filename={0}", info.Name);
Response.TransmitFile(pdfFile);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

This problem is **only** in Safari; IE, Firefox and Chrome download the file correctly every time.  Safari fails 9/10 times.

Any ideas?  We have around 4,000 visitors to the site a month in Safari so this isn't something we can ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try response.writefile instead (think this loads into memory on server first as appose to transmitfile) just to see if it helps.